# Print size of box to latex output

Tags: boxes, output

I need to know the dimensions of many objects in a given unit. Essentially I need the size `\fbox`es would have would I draw ones around the objects. Can I use the typeout command and a modified framebox command to print this information to the latex output?

Comment: What size you need to know : the framebox (with contents) or the contents of the framebox?

Comment: Only contents would be good, but that's not what matters most. It could be the size of the box if that's much easier to get.

Comment: If you know the size of the box, you can calculate the content size too. Do you use `\fbox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's not clear, what `framebox` actually is, I assume `\fbox`.

It's easy to use put the box content first in a `\savebox`, named, say,`\mybox` and ask for the width of it with `\wd\mybox`.

Putting `\fbox` around the content will additionally use `2\fboxrule` and `2\fboxsep` spaces around the normal content, see the output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newbox\mybox
\newbox\myotherbox

\savebox{\mybox}{This is some text}
\savebox{\myotherbox}{\fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}}

\typeout{Box alone:\the\wd\mybox}
\typeout{Whole box:\the\wd\myotherbox}

\typeout{\the\dimexpr2\fboxsep+\the\dimexpr2\fboxrule}
\typeout{Sum of all: \the\dimexpr 2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule+\wd\mybox}


\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This will print out:

```
Box alone:75.44455pt
Whole box:82.24454pt
6.79999pt
Sum of all: 82.24454pt
```

Comment: Excellent. The only thing I had to look up in addition was '\ht' for the height of the box.

Comment: @highsciguy: Oh, sorry, how could I forget `\ht` and `\dp`, two important query routines